# exporting 3D graphics in STL format (for 3D printing)

Tags: export, graphics3d

How do I set the size of the exported item? (`Graphics3D` has no implied unit, so it is not a-priori clear what size the object will be, and experiment indicates that it is generally tiny.

Comment: @Jens Great, thanks!

Comment: Please see [this similar question](http://blender.stackexchange.com/a/7543) which comments on the lack of units in STL format.  Typically, units are defined by the program rendering the STL file.